# Output is not displayed correctly using format{} in python?

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries and i am trying to print its output on the console using the format option in python.
The below program is giving errors while printing the output as desired format mentioned below. The couple of errors which i am encountering are  "**Index is out of range for tuple**, **precision is not in integer format.** Any ideas to resolve these errors and display the output as mentioned below.

### Program

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

temp_list=[{"name": "stevekar", "id": 3, "ip_addr": "10.1.2.3" ,"nm":"24", "neigh": "17.16.1.1",
           "proto": "dhcp", "status":"up", "enabled": True, "ipv6enable": False},
          {"name": "john", "id": 4, "ip_addr": "20.1.1.1" ,"nm":"24", "neigh": "192.168.1.1  192.169.2.6",
           "proto": "static", "status":"up", "enabled": True, "ipv6enable": False},
          {"name": "daren", "id": 6, "ip_addr": "156.1.1.1" ,"nm":"30", "neigh": "19.16.1.2",
           "proto": "dhcp", "status":"up", "enabled": True, "ipv6enable": False}]

fmt = "{}   {}   {}/{}   {}   {}   {}   {}    {}"
print fmt.format("NAME" "ID" "ipaddr" "nm" "neighour" "proto"  "status" "enabled"   "ipv6enable")
print fmt.format( '---------' '---' '----------------' '---' '----------------' '------' '-----' '-----' '--------')

for data_dict in temp_list:
   print fmt.format(data_dict['name'], data_dict['id'],
                data_dict['ip_addr'], data_dict['nm'], data_dict['neigh'],
                data_dict['proto'], data_dict['status'],
                data_dict['enabled'], data_dict['ipv6enable'])
```

I would need the output from the above program is shown below.

Desired output:

```
NAME       ID    ipaddr/nm      neighour        proto    status    enabled   ipv6enable
------    ---   ------------    --------        -----    ------    -------   ---------- 
stevekar   3     10.1.2.3/24    17.16.1.1       dhcp     up        True      False
john       4     20.1.1.1/24    192.168.1.1     static   up        True      False
                                192.169.2.6   
daren      6     156.1.1.1/30   19.16.1.2       dhcp     up        True      False
```

### Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json_format.py", line 11, in <module>
    print fmt.format("NAME" "ID" "ipaddr" "nm" "neighour" "proto"  "status" "enabled"   "ipv6enable")
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Tried with this option as well:

```
fmt = "{:10.10} {:7.7} {:13.13}/{}    {:13.30}  {:9}  {:9}  {:9}  {:}
```

After modification as below:

```
fmt = "{}   {}   {}/{}   {}   {}   {}   {}    {}"
print fmt.format("NAME", "ID", "ipaddr", "nm", "neighour", "proto",  "status", "enabled", "ipv6enable")
print fmt.format( '---------', '---', '----------------', '---', '----------------', '------', '-----', '-----', '--------')
```

Output is shown as

```
NAME   ID   ipaddr/nm   neighour   proto   status   enabled    ipv6enable
---------   ---   ----------------/---   ----------------   ------   -----   -----    --------
stevekar   3   10.1.2.3/24   17.16.1.1   dhcp   up   True    False
john   4   20.1.1.1/24   192.168.1.1  192.169.2.6   static   up   True    False
daren   6   156.1.1.1/30   19.16.1.2   dhcp   up   True    False
```

I have tried to align it properly using:

```
fmt = "{:10.10} {:7.7} {:13.13}/{}    {:13.30}  {:9}  {:9}  {:9}  {:}
```

**Error as:**

```
NAME       ID      ipaddr       /nm    neighour       proto      status     enabled    ipv6enable
---------  ---     -------------/---    ----------------  ------     -----      -----      --------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json_format.py", line 19, in <module>
    data_dict['enabled'], data_dict['ipv6enable'])
ValueError: Precision not allowed in integer format specifier
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need commas in your call to `format` :)

Ex: `fmt.format('NAME', 'ID', ... )`

Comment: Thanks for the answer for tuple error. But, When i am trying to format the output properly the  ValueError: Precision not allowed in integer format specifier (shown above post). Could you please help me.. what is the mistake.